# Battery full notification

Tags: linux, ubuntu, acpi, notifications, battery

I am using a Linux distribution, I didn't get any notification even after the battery is full.

Is there any custom script  to run battery charge status and output a sound notification when the battery is fully charged?

Comment: Which distribution are you using?

Comment: We can't help unless we know your distribution and your desktop environment. Does `acpi` print the battery state on your system?

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I am using Ubuntu, Thank you. yes, acpi print the battery state in my system.

Comment: battery_level=`acpi -b | grep -P -o '[0-9]+(?=%)'`
if [ $battery_level -eq 100 ]
then
    notify-send "Battery low" "Battery level is ${battery_level}%!"
fi

Comment: I have added the above script run as cronjob which making the script execute every minute, like :* * * * * battery_full.sh, Is it work?

Comment: Changing a bit hg8's script (thank you!) and installing it differently, it worked for me, the steps here:
https://runakay.blogspot.com/2019/06/notifying-when-battery-is-full-in-linux.html

Answer (score 6):

I have written a small script that will do that:

[image: screenshot]

---

**Script:**

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
while true
do
    export DISPLAY=:0.0
    battery_percent=$(acpi -b | grep -P -o '[0-9]+(?=%)')
    if on_ac_power; then
        if [ "$battery_percent" -gt 95 ]; then
            notify-send -i "$PWD/batteryfull.png" "Battery full." "Level: ${battery_percent}% "
        fi
    fi
    sleep 300 # (5 minutes)
done
```

---

**Installation:**

Run:

```
sudo apt-get install acpi
git clone https://github.com/hg8/battery-full-notification.git
cd battery-full-notification/
chmod +x batteryfull.sh
```

Copy the script to `~/bin` folder:

```
cp batteryfull.* ~/bin
```

Or copy it to `/usr/local/bin` if you want it to be available for all users on your computer:

```
cp batteryfull.* /usr/local/bin
```

Then add `batteryfull.sh` script as a startup application by:

- Open Dash
- Search for **Startup Applications**
- Double-click the icon
- Click <kbd>Add</kbd> and fill in as follows:

  [image: startup application batteryfull]

Comment: thanks, it's helpful for me,, and nice sound for get attention.. :D

Answer (score 3):

If you're using KDE SC as desktop environment, just do this:

- Open **System Settings**
- Go to **Application and System Notifications** (Section: **Common Appearance and Behavior**)
- If not already selected, choose **Manage Notifications** from the list on the left side
- Select **Power Management System** from the **Event source** drop-down menu
- Click on the list entry **Charge Complete**
- Select any kind of notification/sound: [image: Power Management System Notification Settings]
- Click **Apply**

Answer (score 2):

You can write a custom script that checks `/proc/acpi/battery/BAT0/state` and
gives you the feedback on the line `charging state:` changing to `charged`.
On newer systems you should use `/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/status` if available.

You only would need to check every minute or so, but since you want to know what the previous state was (so it won't beep every minute while it is full), you need to keep the previous state in a file to compare if you start the checking program from crontab, or run a long time process that checks every minute and keeps the previous state internally.

If you have multiple battery bays, you should have multiple entries under `/proc/acpi/battery` (but not under `/sys/class/power_supply/BAT*`) . If one of those entries has no `state`, the battery is not inserted (you can also check the file `info` for the value present)

Comment: The location of the `state` file is not the same on all systems. I don't have a `/proc/acpi/battery/BAT0/stat` file on my LMDE for example.

Answer (score 0):

In case you are using `KDE` / [Manjaro KDE](https://manjaro.org/downloads/official/kde/) like me. It can be configured in system settings. I enabled to start charging at `20%` (search for the `depth of discharge` to know the reason why it is ideal to charge some batteries at `20%`) and stop charging at `80%`.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This Works in KDE 5

[image: KDE alert]

**Installation:**

**Run:**

```
sudo apt-get install acpi
git clone https://github.com/jruedaq/battery-full-notification-KDE5.git
cd battery-full-notification-KDE5/
chmod +x install
./install
```